# facebook successfully logs in but not redirecting to my app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm a noob in android app. i am creating an application which sends app request to my facebook friends, using the method defined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests. 
now i'm having trouble logging in and accessing my app. after providing username and password, i'm logged into facebook and my facebook app asks for permission. after pressing ok, it is not redirecting to send request window, rather shows me the login window again as if i'm not logged in.

here's my full code. please help me.

invite_friends.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_fb_invite"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_click_color_white"
android:text="@string/btn_fb_invite"
/>
```

Invite.java

```
public class Invite extends FragmentActivity {

    private Button pickFriendsButton;
    private UiLifecycleHelper lifecycleHelper;
    boolean pickFriendsWhenSessionOpened;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.invite_friends);

        pickFriendsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_invite);
        pickFriendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //onClickPickFriends();

                if (ensureOpenSession()) {

                    sendRequestDialog();
                }
                else {
                    pickFriendsWhenSessionOpened = true;

                }
            }
        });

        lifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lifecycle helper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
            }
        });
        lifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // ensureOpenSession();


    }



    public void contactInvite(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FindPhnFriends.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }


    private boolean ensureOpenSession() 
    {Toast.makeText(this, "ensure open session method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) 
        {Toast.makeText(this, "no active session or active session is opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Session.openActiveSession(Invite.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
            {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
                {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "open active session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChanged(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            pickFriendsWhenSessionOpened = false;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session state changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendRequestDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "session state not changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private void sendRequestDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

        WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Network Error", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                            if (requestId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Request sent",  
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                })
                .build();
        requestsDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found and answer to my question, here it is:

in ensureOpenSession method, 
replace the condition with

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())
```

and in onSessionStateChanged method,

replace

```
if (state.isOpened())
```

with

```
if (session.isOpened() && state.isOpened())
```